# Can't Enable Gzip-compression in apache 2.2.15

Tags: php, apache, http-compression

I know this has been asked a lot, but, believe me, is not duplicate ;)

I have a Linux server (**CentOS 6.4**) with Apache 2.2.15 Installed.

What do I have?

- I have this line in /**etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf** :

  LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
- I have this line in my **.htaccess** file :

  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

  And I  tried the other versions of enabling mod_deflate in **.htaccess**, too.

And this is my `phpinfo()` screenshot :

[image]

But there is not this header in my response :

```
Content-Encoding : gzip
```

Any Idea?

Comment: Try adding filter by type: `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain`

Comment: I also experience the same problem. And I check phpinfo HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING is not shown. But I don't know how to set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `httpd.conf`, Make sure you have

```
<Directory /PATH/TO/YOUR/APP>
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```